# Object oriented Javascript: event handling

Tags: javascript, oop, dom-events

I'm trying to create an event for an object to have it listen to it. Consider the following example:

```
var moon;

moon = document.createEvent("Event");
moon.initEvent("Event",true,true);

var Dog = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
  
  document.addEventListener("Event",this.bark,false);
};
dog.prototype.bark = function() {
  console.log(this.name + ': Awooooooof Woof!');
};


var spot = new Dog("Spot");
var dot = new Dog("Dot");


//invoke
document.dispatchEvent(moon);
```

I'm expecting to receive an output like:

> Spot: Awooooooof Woof!
>
> Dot: Awooooooof Woof!

But what I get is:

> undefined: Awooooooof Woof!

What is wrong with my example? How can I register a listener that every instance of Dog has?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this line

```
document.addEventListener("Event",this.bark,false);
```

you don't bind the scope of `this.bark` to `this`. In JavaScript, the value of `this` does not depend on where the function is defined but from where it is called. This means when you pass `this.bark` to `addEventListener` you detach it from the current object.

In frameworks like prototype.js and JQuery there are shortcuts for binding `this`, with vanilla JavaScript you can do it like this:

```
function bind(scope, fn) {
   return function() {
      return fn.apply(scope, arguments);
   }
}
```

And then:

```
document.addEventListener("Event",bind(this, this.bark),false);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I figured out how to achieve it with jQuery, but I think that your solution is more elegant.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is that `this` inside the function does not refer to the object you want to manipulate.

How about adding the function `bark` inside the function definition?

```
var Dog = function (name) {
    this.name = name;    
    this.bark = function() {
        console.log(name + ': Awooooooof Woof!');
    };
    document.addEventListener("Event", this.bark, false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

The `this` keyword, inside `Dog.prototype.bark()` points to the object that invoked the method. For example, when `spot.bark()` is called, `this.name` evaluates to `spot.name`, like so:

```
Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
    console.log(spot.name + ': Awooooooof Woof!');
};
```

When the event listener is added inside Dog's constructor, the `document` object is told to listen for that event, and told to call `Dog.prototype.bark()` when it hears that event. This setup is done correctly and the `document` object will call the correct function when it hears that event,

The trouble happens later when the `document` object actually calls the bark function. Now, `this` points to the `document` object, and `this.name` evaluates to `document.name`, like so:

```
Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
    console.log(document.name + ': Awooooooof Woof!');
};
```

`document.name` doesn't exist and that's why the output is: `undefined: Awooooooof Woof!`

**The Fix**

Use [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the provided value to a function's `this` keyword, like so:

```
document.addEventListener("Moon", this.bark.bind(this), false);
```